# Javascript get value of each options inside select

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get each value from options inside a select menu, but I'm struggling to target the element as it has only custom attributes.

Example of html:

```
 <div class="select-wrap">
     <select ng-model="currentTab"> 
        <option value="0">Tab 1</option> 
        <option value="1">Tab 2</option> 
     </select>
 </div>
```

What I'm trying to get:

```
0
1
```

from the

```
option value=""
```

Comment: Is this about [tag:angular]? And why are both options selected?

Comment: @chrisg was a typo and no its not about angular

Comment: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("select[ng-model='currentTab'] > option"), ({value}) => Number(value))` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there’s only one such `<select>` with the given attribute, you can simply use attribute selectors in [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with a mapping function, you can get an array of all values. Remove `Number(` `)`, if converting the values to numbers isn’t desired.

```js
const allValues = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("select[ng-model='currentTab'] > option"), ({value}) => Number(value));

console.log(allValues);
```

```html
<div class="select-wrap">
  <select ng-model="currentTab">
    <option value="0">Tab 1</option>
    <option value="1">Tab 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work

```js
document.querySelectorAll('select[ng-model="currentTab"] option')
.forEach(el=>{
  console.log(el.value)
})
```

```html
 <div class="select-wrap">
     <select ng-model="currentTab"> 
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Tab 1</option> 
        <option value="1" selected="selected">Tab 2</option> 
     </select>
 </div>
```